# phpMyAdmin Setting to not confuse Umlauts

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

This one seems pretty simple but I cant seem to find anything.

My Query ends with: `WHERE b6vjp_user_info.lastname LIKE '%ü%'`

[And these are the results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72LK7.png)

As you see Mysql uses ü and u interchangeably. But I dont know how to stop it from doing that.

Comment: Collation/locale issue. Use a German collation if you only want the ü's.

Comment: @jarlh `utf8_general_ci` isnt the right one?

Comment: Well, take a look at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode-sets.html and see what you can find. (I'm not a MySQL user, so I can't help you with these details.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Either you make a numerical char code check or you use an accent sensitive collation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-collation-names.html). If your query doesn't need unicode normalization (i.e., you check for strings which you know *a priori* that they don't have special needs, like the presence of (visually) indistinguishable glyphs - typically strings that intrinsically come within your own query and not external outputs), I would use **utf8_bin** (only in that particular query):

```
WHERE b6vjp_user_info.lastname LIKE '%ü%' COLLATE utf8_bin
```

Note that this will most likely make the search case-sensitive, hence if you want a case-insensitive sarch you can just use `LOWER(b6vjp_user_info.lastname)`.